# getting server forbidden error in my browser

Tags: node.js

I have just started exploring node.js. Have installed msi file on my windows server. My code below returns me expected output in command window

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

// Send the HTTP header 
// HTTP Status: 200 : OK
// Content Type: text/plain
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

// Send the response body as "Hello World"
response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`');
```

But when i type  `http://127.0.0.1:8081/` in my browser i dont get any output. When i see console i get below error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

What i wrong and how to fix? I am following this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_first_application.htm)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

probably like my current PC, yours too must be running McAfee or some other program is already using port [8081](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8081), you got two options:

- stop McAfee or the other program running on that port
- listen to a different port on your node server

Comment: how to listen to different port?

Comment: you are correct that mccaffe is running but i dont have privelages to stop it

Comment: just change `8081` to some other number,  usually for nodejs port is `3000` for devlopment

Comment: try post 300, and in browser `localhost:3000`, tell me what happens

Comment: wow when i use localhost:3000 it prints outpput so why it doesnt work with 127.0.0.1:3000

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(300);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:300/');
```

I changed it to 300 from 8081 and it worked.

http://127.0.0.1:300/ this url gives the desired output.