# nodejs app on server 403 forbidden

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server

i'm tring upload app on my VPS server I installed `node` v6.11.0 but i get error 403, I uploaded my app to heroku and it work fine. How I can setup my server to run my app with node
here is my heroku test app:

> https://programy123.herokuapp.com/custom

And git

> https://github.com/Bacaaa/programy123

Error I am getting is as follows:

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Server VPS Details:

- Operating System Debian 7.0 - 64bits
- Virtualization Type      (OpenVZ)

I have already done the root folder as `chmod -R 777 root_folder`

Comment: can you describe the VPS details? not the IP, OS type?

Comment: Do I need add something more  ?

Comment: do you know why 403 occurs? I think if you know that then you might probably solve it by your own. You are trying to access something which is forbidden for the user who is requesting. please check if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432070/getting-server-forbidden-error-in-my-browser

Comment: I dont want run app on localhsot but on VPS server i get error 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2 Server at programy-online.com Port 80

Comment: did you try running the server app using super user??

Comment: If i type in console server `node server/` its start my index.js and  page work good on `port 8080` but if i close console server page dont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151297/discussion-between-satish-patel-and-pawel-baca).